# I can't create this table with td colspan and rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

I have a little problem with the `colspan` and `rowspan`. I'm trying to make the following table:

[image: table]

I have tried to create it, but I have difficulties on the first `row`, second `td` when I put it `colspan="2"` and to get the third `td` and put it as `rowspan="2"`. Is this `table` even possible to be created?

Comment: can you show the table that you need to create?

Comment: @GayanS.Muthukumarana this is the table https://i.imgur.com/ZEh10vc.png

Comment: I edited my answer below according to your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`colspan` means we just binding columns. whereas `rowspan` means we are binding rows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px;">
       <table style="color: grey;">
  <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: blue;">test</td>
      <td colspan="2">colspan 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="100px;">test</td>
   <td width="100px;" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: blue;">test</td>
   <td width="100px;">test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">colspan 2</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: blue;">test</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this may help you.